# Computing inverse Laplace transform of Bessel function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to evaluate the inverse Laplace transform of a function that includes the modified Bessel function of the second kind, i.e., my function is f_s = sqrt(a*s)*besselk(1,2*sqrt(a*s)), where a is a constant (say a = 0.5) and 's' is defined as a symbol. To evaluate the inverse Laplace transform of this function, I used the built-in Matlab function 'ilaplace' as transV = ilaplace(f_s,s,t), where I want to evaluate my function at 't' = 2. However, the problem I am getting is that the inverse transformed expression transV still contains 's' variable, which I supposed to transform to 't' after the inverse Laplace transform.

Can anyone help me with what is the problem with this approach? I checked the Matlab documentation and still couldn't figure out the solution. I already tried using 'vpa' function as it was suggested in one of the Matlab forums, but that didn't help to get rid of 's'. I am stuck with this and would really appreciate any help on it.

My code is

```
a = 0.5; t = 2;
syms s;
f_s = sqrt(a*s)*besselk(1,2*sqrt(a*s));
transV = ilaplace(f_s,t); % or transV = vpa(ilaplace(f_s,t));
```

With this, the final result transV still has an expression which is a function of 's' although it should be transformed after ilaplace.

Comment: Judging from the expression returned for `transV`, I think the problem is that Matlab doesn't know how to transform your function `f_s`. In its defence, it looks complicated indeed. Also, you should probably define t as symbolic, and then evaluate at `2` with `subs`

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I already tried doing that but still got problem converting it to the numerical solution.